# How to show workflow in a page using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to create a workflow for document approval process using WF. I need to show this workflow process in a page as how many stages completed,who was involved in the workflow etc. Can you guys please help me out how to achieve. Please share me if you have any source links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WorkflowDesigner to create an image of a workflow and then display that on a web page. But as the WorkflowDesigner is a WPF control doing so in an ASP.NET app is pretty hard.

Comment: Well, there's always the option of rendering the WPF visual to a Bitmap... Not sure how feasible that would be though. :P

Comment: Yes, possible but not easy and it feels very hacky to me.

Comment: Well, if a hack is the only easy way to do it, then it's the best solution for NOW. :P

Answer (score 0):

The idea of trying to produce a bitmap of the WPF is not a bad one. But in general I think what you may be looking at is to create a TrackingParticipant that listens to your workflow events and publishes information somewhere that can later be used to render a web page that suits your needs. So from the TrackingParticipant you could save off each Activity that completes, and then uses some JS based graph library to render this. Not easy, but not impossible either. If your visual needs are not that complicated, this could look more like a report than a flowchart I suppose.

There is a sample of using the TrackingParticipant in the WWF4 samples, VisualWorkflowTracking.